# Pymongo join using lookup

Tags: mongodb, collections, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have two collection :

```
post = {
   "_id" : 102,
   "categories": [
      {'id': ObjectId('6054603f3e1967165a3e70f2'),'name': 'Acting'},
      {'id': ObjectId('605460403e1967165a3e70f6'), 'name': 'Singing'}]
     }
content = {
   "_id" : ObjectId('6054603f3e1967165a3e70f2'),
   "name" : 'Acting'
}
```

So I want join to be :

```
out = [{
   "_id" : 102,
   "name" : ["Acting", "Singing"]}]
```

but after making sure that id for the Acting is same in both the collection.
So for that I am trying a join between two collections.
Here is what I have tried :

```
temp = list(posts.aggregate([
    ...:   {"$unwind" : "$categories"},
    ...:   {"$lookup" : {
    ...:                "from" : "content_categories",
    ...:                "localField" : "categories.id",
    ...:                "foreignField" : "_id",
    ...:                "as" : "temp"
    ...:               }
    ...:   },
    ...:   {"$unwind" : "$temp"},
    ...:   {"$group" : {
    ...:                "_id": "$_id", "name":{"$first":"$temp.name"}
    ...:               }
    ...:   }]))
```

but I am getting only single value of names(I guess first occurance of the id), instead of a list of names.
and I have cross checked that all values are present in temp variable. Then How I should fetch those values as  `name = ["Acting", "Singing"]`.

Comment: You want to get al the values inside the categories array, but check if the id of acting exist on both collection, rigth? But what behavior is expected if the condition is matched or not?

Comment: yes, this is what I want.... I only want value where id's match in both collections and ignore in case of mismatch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me :

```
temp = list(posts.aggregate([
          {"$unwind" : "$categories"},
          {"$lookup" : {
                       "from" : "content_categories",
                       "localField" : "categories.id",
                       "foreignField" : "_id",
                       "as" : "temp"
                     }
          },
          {"$unwind" : "$temp"},
          {"$project" : {
                       "_id": 1, "temp.name" : 1
                      }
          }
        ]))
```